# Number of Motzkin paths which are not Dyck path

Tags: combinatorics

A Dyck path can only move up or down, without crossing the $x$-line.

A Motzkin path is a Dyck path which can also do level steps.

Are there any informations (such as closed-form, asymptotic behavior etc...) on the number of Motzkin paths of length $2n$ which are not Dyck paths ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number ...

Answer (score 3):

https://www.math.ku.edu/~jmartin/courses/math724-F13/count-dyck.pdf

From this source, we see that the number of Dyck paths of length $2n$ is just the Catalan number $C_n$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number

And here, we see that the formula for Motzkin paths of length $2n$ is 
$$M_{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {{2n}\choose{k}}C_k$$